# Clicking Google-map beneath the canvas

Tags: html, google-maps, canvas, html5-canvas

This one is getting  tricky for me.I have the google map in my page which is working properly ,above it lies a canvas. I need to make the google map clickable .i.e when i click on the  canvas ,the map should behave normally .I have added `pointer-events:none;`attribute.It works properly in Firefox ,chrome and IE11.
However my requirement is I need to make it clickable in IE9 on wards,which am unable to replicate. How to do that?

If any one can replicate the behavior in a fiddle ,that will be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

**There's an old jQuery hack that simulates pointer-events:**

Listen for a click event on the canvas and in the click handler:

- Hide the canvas: `$(this).hide();`
- Ask the document to get the element at the clicked xy: `var $map=$(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY);`  (Adjust clientX/Y by any offset to the map/canvas elements) If the map is the only element under your canvas, you could define $map at the start of your app and avoid this step.
- trigger the same event on the google map: `$map.trigger(event);`
- redisplay the canvas: `$(this).show();`